# How to "Run" a .svc WCF Web Service

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

I am working on a project that was last worked on by someone who hasn't been on the team in some time. Having gotten a hold of him to ask him questions about the project and next steps in general, I was told I need to run a Java web service. After not being able to find any .jws files in our network, I asked if a particular .svc (WCF Web Service) file was the right service and was told to "run [filename]" which is the .svc file. This file is in a directory with some relevant Java class files that appear to have been part of an eclipse project (which I am unable to open).

Now I've looked around and all tutorials I can find about running a .svc file involve a visual studio project and creating the project from scratch, not just running a single .svc file as a web service. I'm new to Windows in general and haven't seen a .svc file. Does it make since to say to simply "run" a .svc WCF Web Service? And does it make since that a .svc file would be created from a Java project? If so, how would I simply run that service?

I hope this question made sense. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .svc file? It's just text, you can open it with an editor.

Comment: A .svc file is a service file for WCF.  You don't "run" it, you host it.  A single .svc file isn't going to do you much good, unless the code for the service implementation is in the .svc file (usually it's in the code-behind).

Comment: You are correct. It was ambiguous to me because the code I received was not up to date or pulled down from source control to the proper machine. It turns out when the guy said "run" it,  he meant the entire Java project from a debugger in some IDE (Intellij IDEA) that was on his old machine. So that's why it didn't make any sense. Thanks for the help though y'all!